# An infinitely axiomatizable class of structures whose reduct is finitely axiomatizable, and vice versa

Tags: model-theory

Let $L$ and $L'$ be first-order languages such that $L' \subseteq L$. Does there exist a class $K$ of $L$-structures which is axiomatizable but not finitely axiomatizable, such that the $L'$ reduct of $K$ is finitely axiomatizable? Also, what about vice versa? That is, does there exist a class $K$ of $L$-structures which is finitely axiomatizable, such that the $L'$ reduct of $K$ is axiomatizable but not finitely axiomatizable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are possible.

First, an easy fact: we can find consistent theories $T_1$, $T_2$ in disjoint finite languages $\Sigma_1,\Sigma_2$ respectively, such that $T_1$ is finitely axiomatizable, $T_2$ is not finitely axiomatizable, and neither $T_1$ nor $T_2$ have finite models.

*(For example, let $T_1$ be the theory of dense linear orders without endpoints, and let $T_2$ be any finite-language non-finitely-axiomatizable complete theory - note that a complete theory in a finite language which has a finite model is finitely axiomatizable.)*

Now here's how we can apply this fact:

**A finitely axiomatizable class with a non-finitely-axiomatizable reduct**: if $L'=\emptyset$ and $L=\Sigma_1$, then the class of $L'$-reducts of models of $T_1$ (= the class of infinite sets) is not finitely axiomatizable even though the class of models of $T_1$ is finitely axiomatizable.

**A non-finitely-axiomatizable class with finitely-axiomatizable reduct**: Let $L=\Sigma_1\cup \Sigma_2$, $L'=\Sigma_1$. A model of the theory $$S=\{\varphi\wedge\psi:\varphi\in T_1,\psi\in T_2\}$$ basically consists of a model of $T_1$ "glued" to a model of $T_2$ of the same cardinality. This means that the class of $L'$-reducts of models of $S$ is just the class of models of $T_1$, which is finitely axiomatizable; but $S$ itself is non-finitely-axiomatizable, since $T_2$ is.