# Are the field reducts of real closed fields finitely axiomatizable?

Tags: model-theory

This is a follow-up to my previous question on real closed fields, here: [Are the field reducts of real closed fields first-order axiomatizable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4045146/are-the-field-reducts-of-real-closed-fields-first-order-axiomatizable). In that question, I asked whether the $\{+,-,*,0,1\}$ reducts of real closed fields are axiomatizable. Now, in this current question, I am asking whether they are finitely axiomatizable. This is not quite trivial, because [there are](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4477070/an-infinitely-axiomatizable-class-of-structures-whose-reduct-is-finitely-axiomat) infinitely axiomatizable classes of structures whose reduct is finitely axiomatizable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [my answer to your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4045155/28111) said, real closed fields are *basically equivalent to* their field reducts: we can recover (in a definable, uniform way) the ordering given just the field structure. This means that from a finite axiomatization of the class of "real closeable fields" we could recover a finite axiomatization of the class of real closed fields itself.

In general, whenever we're dealing with two "uniformly-inter-definable" classes of structures like this, properties like finite axiomatizability transfer from one to the other.